How to fix vulnerable version of a sub-dependency(with fixed version) using overrides in package.json
I'm trying to fix a vulnerability in a sub-dependency of a library in my JavaScript project. Specifically, the package @paralleldrive/feature-toggles@1.0.4 uses an outdated version of lodash@4.17.11, which has known vulnerabilities.
I attempted to use the overrides configuration in my package.json to force the version of lodash to 4.17.21, but I get an error:
├─┬ @paralleldrive/feature-toggles@1.0.4 overridden
│ └── lodash@4.17.11 invalid: "^4.17.21" from node_modules/@paralleldrive/feature-toggles overridden

Here’s my package.json file:
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@paralleldrive/feature-toggles": "^1.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@paralleldrive/feature-toggles": {
      "lodash": "4.17.21"
    }
  }
}

It's important to mention that the @paralleldrive/feature-toggles package has a direct version dependency on lodash@4.17.11 (without the ^ sign), which means it is locked to exactly that version, not allowing for higher versions.
Here's the package.json file of @paralleldrive/feature-toggles:
{
  "name": "@paralleldrive/feature-toggles",
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "4.17.11"
  }
}

Since it's using an exact version rather than a flexible version (which would allow the ^ sign for version ranges), npm install still throws the error above, and lodash@4.17.11 is not being updated to the intended version.
How can I properly override this sub-dependency to force lodash@4.17.21 in this case?
Environment:

Node.js version: 16.19.1

npm version:9.5.1


Any help would be appreciated!
